# Why is return from MessageBox.Show not "DialogResult.Cancel" when the close button is pressed?

Tags: vb.net, forms, messagebox

I'm using the following code:

```
Dim Reply As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("GOT IT!")
If Reply = DialogResult.OK Then '...`
```

When I click the `Close` button (red "X" in corner) the condition looking for `DialogResult.OK` still evaluates to true and when I check the `Reply` variable's value at runtime after clicking the close button it is `1 {OK}`.

From the documentation on [MessageBox Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx) it says:

> Displays a message window, **also known as a dialog box**, which
>   presents a message to the user. It is a modal window, blocking other
>   actions in the application until the user closes it. A MessageBox can
>   contain text, buttons, and symbols that inform and instruct the user.

While I find the documentation on [DialogBoxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632588(v=vs.85).aspx) a little convoluted and confusing, it appears to me (and i could be bery wrong) that the `Close` button should by default set the return to `IDCancel` which, I must assume is somehow parsed by the `MessageBox` class into `DialogReturn.Cancel`.

**So why does `MessageBox` not show the return form the close button as `DialogResult.Cancel`??**

---

This is all very confusing to me because it seems the `MessageBox` class is not consistent with other forms from within the same `Systems.Windows.Forms` namespace.

For instance, if we look at the documentation from the [Form Class's .DialogResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) method, it specifically tells us the return from the close button is `DialogResult.Cancel`:

> When a form is displayed as a modal dialog box, clicking the Close
>   button (the button with an X in the top-right corner of the form)
>   causes the form to be hidden and the DialogResult property to be set
>   to DialogResult.Cancel.

Comment: That wont compile as is.  Did you mean `Dim Reply = MessageBox.Show("GOT IT!")` ?

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste/delete error!  My code is actually `Dim Reply As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("GOT IT!")` - I'll edit the question for future readers ;)

Comment: You could get IDCancel only if you add a MessageBoxButtons enum that include the Cancel option IE _MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel_

Comment: Hi @steve - could you provide any references for this requirement?  just so I can learn more about how the MessageBox button works.  Thanks!

Comment: [This is from the WinAPI version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx), not really a solid proof reference but the section about the Return value talks about the behvior when the cancel button is present, Then trial and error confirm this behavior

Comment: If you dont specify Cancel as one of the button options for the third arg, the X wont map to a result you did not specify was legal.  The red "X" wont event be enabled.  The form you used - no buttons specified - is the same as `OKOnly`

Comment: @Plutonix - I can assure you the red "X" is enabled using the code I posted above - I am definitely able to click it, and it returns `DialogBox.OK`, as my question states :)

Comment: If you specify  buttons like "Abort Retry Ignore" which doesnt define Cancel, it wont be enabled.  That creepy short form isnt really a Dialog but a simple message box.  The larger point is, it wont return a value you didnt specify as valid.

Comment: @Steve - that is a great link.  I would assume then that the .Net `MessageBox ` class is basically just a wrapper for the WinAPI `MessageBox` template for `DialogBox`.  Maybe you could expand your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the comments above, you could get `IDCancel` result when clicking the Close Red Button, only if you add a MessageBoxButtons enum that include the Cancel option For example *MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel* and others.

The `MessageBox.Show` method is indeed a wrapper around the [WinApi MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) function. You could see this wrapping looking at the [reference sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MessageBox.cs,415)

The behavior of MessageBox.Show is different from the link that you have pointed. That one is relative to the WinForm engine and of course the behavior of the WinForm Form class is totally managed by the library to handle the scenarios presumed for a WinForm class.

In the WinApi documentation you could find a subtle reference in the section about the Return value where they talks about the behavior when the cancel button is present. Then trial and error confirms this assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in MessageBoxButtons as an override that includes a cancel button  so like MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel.

```
Dim message As String = "GOT IT!"
Dim caption As String = "Fancy Caption"
Dim Reply As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
If Reply = DialogResult.OK Then '...`
```

If you dont want the caption than skip it but you'll still need a comma, like:

```
MessageBox.Show("GOT IT!",,MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons(v=vs.110).aspx) for full enumeration of options for MessageBoxButtons.

Comment: Thanks JasonHughes - but could you elaborate as to *why* I need to provide an enumerator that contains a `Cancel` button?  My question was not how to get a cancel button, but rather why the return doesn't work in the first place - I'd like to understand the nature behind this.  Thanks!!

Comment: I believe because you are looking for equality.  You are looking to see if the DialogResult is equal to a DialogResult.Ok for a Dialog that only contains an Ok option.  You might be able to use the override that contains the default button and set that to cancel.  Its been a while since I've dabbled in winforms.  Out of the box I believe the default is the first button, so if all you have is an OK button than that is the default button.  I'd have to open up an IDE and confirm.

Comment: Also the MessageBox Class inherits from the Object Class not from Forms Class, and they both have something called a DialogResult. So even though they are in same assembly they are not the exact same type of object, the DialogResult for the MessageBox appears more directly suited for the MessageBox UI.

Comment: Thanks for the response and explanation - what you say makes sense.  I chose Steve's answer because he provided the reference to the MSDN Source which shows the WinAPI function that defines the behavior you described, but I would venture to say both answers are correct :)